# Error msg in the proc is not displayed in the app

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("No_Products_Qty_below_zero_proc", con);
comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ReceiptNo", SqlDbType.Decimal)).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(label4.Text);
comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SNO", SqlDbType.Decimal)).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(label14.Text);
comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@qty_sold", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@amount_price", SqlDbType.Decimal)).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(label12.Text);
comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@discount", SqlDbType.Decimal)).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(label18.Text);

if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
    con.Close();
    con.Open();
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
else if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
      con.Open();
      comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
      con.Close();
}

textBox1.Text = "";
textBox2.Text = "";

MessageBox.Show("Inserted successfully!");
```

Comment: What do you mean by _not executing well_ exactly?

Comment: comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; is missing

Comment: Thank you Experts, When the qty <0, it does not popup the error msg like in SQL server

Comment: Have you seen that in your call you don't provide the discount parameter?

Comment: Why don't you use directly the name of the stored procedure instead of calling Exec?